# How to create a GUI without a frame in X11?

Tags: c++, linux, qt, x11

I'm trying to figure out how to create a graphical interface, in X11, which exists outside of a window manager's/desktop environment's standard window frame. For example, when Thunderbird finds new mail, it shows a special alert in the lower right hand corner of the screen which is shown without any frame (no close/minimize buttons, etc.).

I'm specifically interested in doing this in QT with C++, but if someone knows a solution with a different graphical library, that would be helpful too.

Answer (score 3):

For QT pass Qt::FramelessWindowHint as a window flag when you construct your top level widget.

See here for more info:

http://doc.qt.nokia.com/main-snapshot/qt.html#WindowType-enum

You can do this with X as well although I haven't done so in a long time.

http://www.xfree86.org/current/XCreateWindow.3.html

Answer (score 1):

With GTK you would use gtk_window_set_decorated(), which would probably be Gtk::Widget->set_decorated() (I think, I don't use gtkmm).

`http://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/unstable/classGtk_1_1Window.html#a67adb1d8051a38e0e5272f141bb8778c`